# Exception when printing out ManyToMany entity

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jackson

I am creating a simple project using Spring Data JPA to learn.

I have this entity (getters/setters removed for clarity):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "shop")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"barbers"})
public class Shop {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "idshop")
    private int shopID;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "address")
    private String address;

    //THIS SHOWS HOW MANY BARBERS WORKS IN THIS SHOP - CHILD
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "shops", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    private Set<Barber> barbers = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    public Set<Barber> getBarbers(){

        return barbers;
    }

    public void removeBarber(Barber barber)
    {
        barbers.remove(barber);
        barber.getShops().remove(this);
    }

    public void addBarber(Barber barber)
    {
        barbers.add(barber);
        barber.getShops().add(this);
    }

    public Shop() {
    }

    public Shop(String name, String address) {
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
    } this.address = address;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Shop{" +
                "id=" + shopID +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", address='" + address + '\'' +
                ", barbers='" + barbers + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

I have a simple controller which pretty fetches the requested shop from the repository and returns that. When I do a System.out.println(), I can see the following: `Shop{id=3, name='fade', address='hammersmith', barbers='[Barber{id=1, name='bob', rating='4'}]'}`

But when the controller returns the object, I get the following exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: com.gogobarber.barber.entities.Shop$HibernateProxy$U83qWd1X["hibernateLazyInitializer"])
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:77) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.reportBadDefinition(SerializerProvider.java:1300) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DatabindContext.reportBadDefinition(DatabindContext.java:400) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.failForEmpty(UnknownSerializer.java:46) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.serialize(UnknownSerializer.java:29) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:728) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:774) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:480) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
```

I have a good idea that the error is stemming from marshalling the pojo into a json string and that the cause of the error is likely to be the from the `Set<Barber>` (despite the error talking about not finding a serializer for byteBuddy.. what is this?). Is it usual to always configure the jackson object mapper? I'm assuming jackson should be advanced enough to tackle a Set? Maybe it's because the way I've configured my ManyToMany relationship?

EDIT = This is my controller and Barber class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "barber")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"shops"})
public class Barber {

public Barber() {
}

public Barber(String name, String rating) {
    this.name = name;
    this.rating = rating;
}

public int getBarberId() {
    return barberId;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getRating() {
    return rating;
}

public void setRating(String rating) {
    this.rating = rating;
}

public Set<Shop> getShops() {
    return shops;
}

//THIS FETCHES THE SHOPS THE BARBER IS ASSOCAITED TO - PARENT
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
@JoinTable(name = "barberworkinshops",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "Barber_ID", referencedColumnName = "idbarber"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "Shop_ID", referencedColumnName = "idshop")
)
private Set<Shop> shops = new LinkedHashSet<>();;

public void addBarberToShop(Shop shop)
{
    shops.add(shop);
    shop.getBarbers().add(this);
}

public void removeBarberFromShop(Shop shop)
{
    shops.remove(shop);
    shop.getBarbers().remove(this);
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "idbarber")
private int barberId;

@Column(name = "Name")
private String name;

@Column(name = "Rating")
private String rating;

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return "Barber{" +
            "id=" + barberId +
            ", name='" + name + '\'' +
            ", rating='" + rating + '\'' +
            ", shops='" + shops + '\'' +
            '}';
}
}
```

Controller:

```
@RestController
public class ShopController {

@Autowired
private BarberRepo barberRepo;

@Autowired
private ShopRepo shopRepo;


@GetMapping("/shop/{id}")
public Shop getShop(@PathVariable String id)
{
    Shop shop = shopRepo.getById(Integer.valueOf(id));
    System.out.println(shop);
    return shop;
}

@PostMapping("/shop/{name}/{address}")
public Shop createShop(@PathVariable String name, @PathVariable String address)
{
    Shop shop = new Shop(name, address);
    return shopRepo.save(shop);
}

@PatchMapping("/shop/{sId}/addBarber/{bId}")
public Shop addBarber(@PathVariable String sId, @PathVariable String bId)
{
    Shop shop = shopRepo.getById(Integer.valueOf(sId));
    Barber b = barberRepo.getById(Integer.parseInt(bId));
    shop.addBarber(b);
    Shop save = shopRepo.save(shop);
    return save;
}
}
```

Comment: try adding **@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})**  before Set<Barber>

Comment: please add minimum code to reproduce, Barberc lass  and YourController ...

Comment: @ZakirHussain - Tried that, didn't work. Still same exeption

Comment: @HuyNguyen - edited. Question now has Barber and controller

Answer (score 0):

As far  as i see you use lazy load in Shop entity for barber collection...

It might be a problematic if it is fetched out of transaction or serialize through jackson ...

I suggest you can do a few thing to avoid the error in console log.

1- Load barber collections in service, personally, i would like to create more Service Layer to interact with DB Repo Layer, you can create ShopService to manage it, you can force to load by simple method:
shop.getBarbers().size(); // force to fetch entity in the same transaction

2- add @JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"}) for each entity

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
```

3- set jackson option fail-on-empty-beans=false.

```
spring.jackson.serialization.fail-on-empty-beans=false
```

or

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS);
```